# Emulator: WARNING | *** No gRPC protection active, consider launching with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.***

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have encountered this error message while trying to launch my MLkit face detector app project. There is also 'unexpected system image feature string' problem, and my emulator is updated.

This is the event log:

```
1:07 PM Gradle sync started

1:07 PM * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

1:07 PM * daemon started successfully

1:07 PM Gradle sync finished in 2 s 306 ms (from cached state)

1:07 PM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project G:\TestFaceDetection

1:08 PM Emulator: WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.

1:08 PM Emulator: WARNING | *** No gRPC protection active, consider launching with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.***

1:08 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0

1:09 PM Gradle build finished in 1 m 51 s 271 ms
```

I am a newby, so please help me resolve the problem

Hint:

I believe the problem is caused by moving .android and .AndroidStudio4.0 folders, since I they appeared after I did so. It was necessary because my user folder contains cyrillic characters and it is too late to change it.So I moved those android folders to C:\android and changed some environmental variables in accordance:
[env vars for a user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoxEz.png)

and

[system env vars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5NN2.png)

As per 'considering launching with with the -grpc-use-jwt flag, as far as I understood it means running an app with the flag, but I dont have an .apk file for that. Most probably I am wrong but I didn't find anything on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an apk to launch the emulator with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.

1. First get the latest emulator for your environment.
2. run `emulator -grpc-use-jwt` from command line prompt. If it is not in the path add to the path.

Detailed explanation [here](https://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1853).